# converting my custom CSV format string to dict in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a method in python that receives a dict and in that dict two variables itself contains the variables which is in some CSV format and i want to convert that variable of variables into a separate dict so that i get the the value of some field in first variable in second variable.

```
dict = {'type':'test',
        'names':'\"type\",\"value,id\",\"count\"',
        'values':'\"test\",\"123\",\"1\"'}
```

I want to get the the value of count that is 1.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that "in that dict two variables" are key and value in dictionary and you want to set some values to other dictionaries and then get them you can probably do something like this.

> Note that dictionaries are key value pairs and you get values by keys, which are many times of type string.

One way to create dictionaries like that is:

```
my_dict = dict(x=dict(a = 1), y=dict(b=dict(c = 2, d = 3)))
```

The line above is basically this.

```
{
  x: {a: 1},
  y: {
    b: {
      c: 2,
      d: 3
    }
  }
}
```

Access the values:

```
my_dict['x'] ## output - {'a': 1}
my_dict['x']['a'] ## output - 1
```

Ddd/update items pairs to dictionary:

```
my_dict['z'] = 4
my_dict['x']['e'] = 5
```

After all changes *my_dict* would probably look like this.

```
{
  x: {
      a: 1,
      e: 5
  },
  y: {
    b: {
      c: 2,
      d: 3
    }
  },
  z: 4
}
```

Remove items:

```
del a['x'] ## or
a.pop('x')
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i have the value in the format:-'names':'\"type\",\"value,id\",\"count\"' format. I want to first split that into individual fields.How can i split it and get the values? I am not setting the values but i got input in this format and i have to return the value corresponding to count in my example.